# Should I separate a variable that changes often into a different entity although it is contextually should be inside another entity?

Tags: architecture, ios, immutability, swift-language

So, I have an entity called `Consultation` that is being used as a member variable of the class `VideoCallViewModel` that goes like this:

```
struct Consultation: Equatable {
    enum Status: Int, CaseIterable {
        case pending = 100
        case dropped = 150
        case ready = 200
        case created = 300
        case inProgress = 500
        case inRating = 700
        case completed = 900
    }
    let id: String
    let serviceId: String
    let serviceName: String
    let status: Status?
    let customer: Customer?
    let provider: Provider?
}

protocol GetConsultationProtocol {
    func get(for consultationId: String) -> Observable<Consultation>
}

final class GetConsultation: GetConsultationProtocol {
    private let getConsultationApi: (String, String) -> Single<Data>
    private let authInfo: () -> AuthInfo?
        
    init(getConsultationApi: @escaping (String, String) -> Single<Data>,
         authInfo: @escaping () -> AuthInfo?) {
        self.getConsultationApi = getConsultationApi
        self.authInfo = authInfo
    }
    
    func get(for consultationId: String) -> Observable<Consultation> {
        guard let accessToken = authInfo()?.accessToken.token else {
            return .error(AuthenticationError.notAuthenticated)
        }
        
        return getConsultationApi(consultationId, accessToken)
            .asObservable()
            .map { try ConsultationResponseModel.decode(from: $0,
                                                        keyDecodeStrategy: .convertFromSnakeCase) }
            .map { $0.toConsultation() }
    }
}
```

Now, the `status` variable will change a lot depending on what status will the app get from the backend. However, the API will return the `status` along with the whole `Consultation`. So the app will get a new `Consultation` with the same data except for the `status`. Because I need the `Consultation` to be immutable, I've been meaning to separate the `status` (the only one who can change value) to something like this instead, and treat both of them as different entities.

```
struct Consultation: Equatable {
    let id: String
    let serviceId: String
    let serviceName: String
    let status: ConsultationStatus?
    let customer: Customer?
    let provider: Provider?
}

struct VideoCallConsultation: Equatable {
    let id: String
    let serviceId: String
    let serviceName: String
    let customer: Customer?
    let provider: Provider?

    init(from consultation: Consultation) {
        self.id = consultation.id
        self.serviceId = consultation.serviceId
        self.serviceName = consultation.serviceName
        self.customer = consultation.customer
        self.provider = consultation.provider
    }
}

enum ConsultationStatus: Int, CaseIterable {
    case pending = 100
    case dropped = 150
    case ready = 200
    case created = 300
    case inProgress = 500
    case inRating = 700
    case completed = 900
}

protocol GetConsultationProtocol {
    func get(for consultationId: String) -> Observable<Consultation>
    func getForVideoCall(for consultationId: String) -> Observable<VideoCallConsultation, ConsultationStatus?>
}

final class GetConsultation: GetConsultationProtocol {
    private let getConsultationApi: (String, String) -> Single<Data>
    private let authInfo: () -> AuthInfo?
        
    init(getConsultationApi: @escaping (String, String) -> Single<Data>,
         authInfo: @escaping () -> AuthInfo?) {
        self.getConsultationApi = getConsultationApi
        self.authInfo = authInfo
    }
    
    func get(for consultationId: String) -> Observable<Consultation> {
        guard let accessToken = authInfo()?.accessToken.token else {
            return .error(AuthenticationError.notAuthenticated)
        }
        
        return getConsultationApi(consultationId, accessToken)
            .asObservable()
            .map { try ConsultationResponseModel.decode(from: $0,
                                                        keyDecodeStrategy: .convertFromSnakeCase) }
            .map { return $0.toConsultation() }
    }

    func getForVideoCall(for consultationId: String) -> Observable<VideoCallConsultation, ConsultationStatus?> {
        return get(consultationId)
            .map { return (VideoCallConsultation(from: $0), $0.status?) }
    }
}
```

The logic for adding a new `VideoCallConsultation` entity is like this:

- The `Consultation` entity will have an immutable status **EXCEPT** in the
  VideoCall bounded context. Eg. `Consultation` entity is needed only to get the current value of the `Consultation` for displaying the status in the Dashboard of the app.
- If we only use the immutable `Consultation` and the mutable `ConsultationStatus` as the member variables, then we will have two instances of status which will probably confuse the programmer.

Does this make sense? I mean, contextually, `ConsultationStatus` should be inside the `Consultation`, right? However, because of the mutability nature of the `ConsultationStatus` in the VideoCall context (ie. when the video call view controller is presented), if I get the whole consultation just to get the current status, I also need to update the whole `Consultation`.

Or is it just a case of over-engineering on my part, because I know that I can make it so much simpler if I were to make the `Consultation.status` variable a `var` instead of a `let` to make it mutable. However, I was hesitant to use `var` because IMHO it breaks the symmetry and immutability of the whole entity (because all of the rest of the entity are immutable `lets`).

So, any suggestion or thought about this? Thanks in advance.